# Dynamical Behavior of Hurst Exponent

Tags: market-data, brownian-motion, dynamic, hurst-exponent

I feel that the dynamic of financial market is not really modeled by standard Brownian motion, but fractional Brownian motion or even multifractional Brownian motion.

I have read some references on Hurst exponent of stock prices and I get a feeling that the Hurst exponent may be random, too, since:

1. It should be mean-reversion
2. It has fluctuation around crisis.

May I ask what else empirical properties Hurst exponent should follow?

Are there any reference on modeling it?

Thank you so much!

Ref:

[image: HURST EXPONENT AND FINANCIAL MARKET PREDICTABILITY]

Comment: @Emma actually it is figure 2.3 in the 3rd paper you suggested makes me ask this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hurst exponents are most often used in identifying trends in time series.

It's been quite a while, but I read this book years ago and this sort of thing is addressed therein (albeit, in a somewhat superficial manner as typical for any trading-centric modeling).  Might be worth checking this out.

[https://www.amazon.com/Chaos-Order-Capital-Markets-Volatility/dp/0471139386](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471139386)